# Form to perform two different actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, forms

I have a form tag in my aspx page with a submit button.

```
<form id="userReg"  method="post">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="doActions();" />
</form>
```

When I click on the submit button I want to do two different actions i.e., to redirect to another webform and secondly to redirect to another url.

**Javascript**

```
        function doActions() {
        userForm = document.getElementById('userReg');
        userForm.action = 'GettingUserDetails.aspx';
        userForm.submit();
        userForm.action = 'Confirmationurl.com';
        userForm.submit();
    }
```

It is performing the `'GettingUserDetails.aspx'` action after that it is not doing the `Confirmationurl.com` action.

How can I perform both the actions

Comment: Do the first submit via Ajax, or do a redirect in the response from the first submit.

Comment: Pass the second function in a callback?

Comment: `userForm = document.getElementById('userReg'); userForm2 = userForm; `  now try submit function on `userForm` and `userForm2`

Comment: @nnnnnn Tq, I will give a try on this

Comment: @nnnnnn if I try using ajax I'm not able to retrieve the form values. Ex: `Request.Form["first_name"]` is giving null even though it has a value

Comment: @Giri Can you give a sample example

Comment: @Hirenpatel Hey, its not working as you have said

Comment: function doActions(arg, callback){
        userForm = document.getElementById('userReg');
        userForm.action = 'GettingUserDetails.aspx';
        userForm.submit();
        userForm.action = 'Confirmationurl.com';
        userForm.submit();
} disregard this. - can't seem to delete this comment

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name=Form1 action= "login1.php" method=post>
Username <input type="text" name="username">
Password <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="button1" 
                     onclick="return OnButton1();">
```

Now, we have got a form. When we click the Submit button, it calls a JavaScript function:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function OnButton1()
{
    document.Form1.action = "GettingUserDetails.aspx"    // First target
    document.Form1.target = "iframe1";    // Open in a iframe
    document.Form1.submit();        // Submit the page
    document.Form1.action = "Confirmationurl.com"    // Second target
    document.Form1.target = "iframe2";    // Open in a iframe
    document.Form1.submit();        // Submit the page
    return true;
}
-->
</script>
```

OK, now we are submitting the data to two pages. As you can see they have got a target like a frame. This is because we need it to open the two new pages with the data, but for not bothering the user we hide the IFRAMEs like this:

```
<div style="visibility:hidden">
<iframe NAME="iframe1" WIDTH="40" HEIGHT="40"></iframe>
<iframe NAME="iframe2" WIDTH="40" HEIGHT="40"></iframe>
</div>
```

The page will send the data to IFRAME and the information will be processed as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Ajax, would make it even better.

```
function doActions() {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: "GettingUserDetails.aspx",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function() {
        // callback code here
           userForm.action = 'Confirmationurl.com';
           userForm.submit();
       }
    })

}

$(userForm).on('submit', function(ev){
 ev.preventDefault();
 doActions();
}
```